# Workaround for Filtering Datetime in Qdrant using Python SDK

Tags: python, qdrant

I am working with Qdrant, a vector database, and I need to filter data based on datetime values using the Python SDK. However, I encountered an issue where Qdrant expects numerical input but receives datetime, leading to parsing errors.

**Here is a simplified version of my code:**

```
from datetime import datetime
from qdrant_client import QdrantClient

# Qdrant client setup
qdrant_client = QdrantClient(...)

# Datetime string to filter
datetime_obj = 2024-02-22 10:04:28.658690

# Filter query
query = {
    "bool": {
        "filter": {
            "range": {
                "timestamp": {"gte": datetime_obj }
            }
        }
    }
}

# Execute query
result = qdrant_client.query(query)
```

**The error message I receive is:**

Input should be a valid number:

```
[type=float_type, input_value=datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 22, 10, 5, 46, 966824), input_type=datetime]
```

Comment: https://qdrant.tech/documentation/concepts/filtering/#datetime-range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qdrant will support datetime in the upcoming v1.8.0 release.

You can try converting the value to integer timestamps/epochs and use range-based filtering.
https://qdrant.tech/documentation/concepts/filtering/#range